# Find the expression of $A^n$

Tags: matrices

I'm wondering about this exercize :

Let $A=\frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 &1 \\1 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 &0  \end{bmatrix}$ Compute $A^2,A^3$ then $A^n \ \forall \ n \ \in \mathbb{N}$

I've computed $A^2=\begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 0 & 0.5 &0 \\0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 &0 \\ 0 & 0.5 & 0 &0.5  \end{bmatrix}$ and $A^3=A$

So if $n$ is pair then A equals the same matrice as $A^2$ otherwise if odd $A^n=A$ but is it possible to determine an unique expression for $A^n$ ?

Thank

Comment: It is possible using $(-1)^n$ but there is no point. I would just leave it at that

Comment: The upper-right entry in $A^2$ should *not* be a $1$.  Is that a typo?  Also, what do you mean by "unique"?

Comment: yes indeed it's a 0, I meant an explicit version like you've just showed me thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an explicit expression, you could write something like
$$
A^n = 
\frac 14 
\pmatrix{
1 + (-1)^n & 1 + (-1)^{n+1}&1 + (-1)^n &1 + (-1)^{n+1}\\
1 + (-1)^{n+1}&1 + (-1)^n & 1 + (-1)^{n+1}&1 + (-1)^n \\
1 + (-1)^n &1 + (-1)^{n+1}&1 + (-1)^n & 1 + (-1)^{n+1}\\
1 + (-1)^{n+1}&1 + (-1)^n & 1 + (-1)^{n+1}&1 + (-1)^n 
}
$$

---

**Note:** this computation could be made easier by using the tensor (i.e. [Kronecker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Definition)) product. In particular, we note that
$A = B \otimes C$, where 
$$
B = \frac 12 \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}, \quad C = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
$$
It follows that
$$
A^n = B^n \otimes C^n = 
B \otimes \pmatrix{
1 + (-1)^n & 1 + (-1)^{n+1}\\
1 + (-1)^{n+1} & 1 + (-1)^n 
}
$$